# can RCAP2H and RCAP2L be used with reg51.h?

Tags: microcontroller, 8051

So we know that the newer versions of 8051 like AT89S8253 has the functions RCAP2H and RCAP2L that is used to capture the low byte and high byte values in timer2. I wanted to know how we could implement the same capturing of values using timer0 or timer1 in a standard AT89C51 that does not have timer2.

Answer (score 0):

No, the standard timers of the 8051 (timer0 and timer1) don't have any capture capabilities.

See chapters 2.9 to 2.11 of the [Atmel 8051 Microcontrollers Hardware Manual](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/doc4316.pdf).

**Edit**

You could implement capturing in software by saving the contents of THx and TLx in a variable. But you need some procedure to get the right value if the counter rolls over from 0x??FF to 0x??00, for example check TFx. Beware of interrupts between reading THx and TLx.